# Connecting aspera on cloud with S3bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, buckets

I used this policy on AWS to try connecting AoC with an S3 bucket:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::880559705280:role/atp-aws-us-east-1-ts-atc-node"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Condition": {
        "StringLike": {
          "sts:ExternalId": "crn:v1:bluemix:public:aspservice-service:global:a/2dd2425e9a424641a12855a1fd5e85ee:70740386-6ca4-4473-bf9b-69a1fd22be12:::c1893698-abfa-4934-a7ca-1a6d837df5e0"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

but when copied on Bucket Policy, I receive `Error: Statement is missing required element.`

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to paste this policy file into `Trust relationship policy` in Role tab.